# How to show that $\mathbb{Z}_5[i] = \{a + bi:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_5 \}$ is a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

A set with modular arithmetic is given:
$$(\mathbb{Z}_5[i], +_5, \cdot_5)$$
$$\mathbb{Z}_5[i] = \{a + bi: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_5\}$$
I am to show that this set is a ring. Of course I would like to show that is it a subring but I don't know which one could be the "bigger" ring.

Comment: The problem is ill-posed unless you specify how the operations on this set are defined.

Comment: @egreg I think I did it.

Comment: @Hendrra No, you only introduced the symbols.

Comment: @egreg but I highlighted that the there is a set given with modular arithmetic. Isn't that enough knowing that we're considering $\mathbb{Z_5}$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Modular connectedness is not nice to show. That's why I wanted to show that my set is a subring. But I don't know which one could be the ring with $\mathbb{Z_5[i]}$ as a subset

Comment: @MorganRodgers That's exactly my question. Is it possible to find a ring that $\mathbb{Z_5[i]}$ is a subring of. I meant associativity. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_5[i]\cong \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x^2+1)\cong \mathbb Z_5[x]/(x-2)(x+2) \cong \mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_5 $, so $\mathbb Z_5[i]$ is a ring.

Comment: And it’s not a field.

Comment: yes, because $x^2+1=(x+2)(x+3)$ reducible in $\mathbb Z_5$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two natural interpretations for $\mathbb{Z}_5[i]$:

- $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$
- $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2+1)$

They are actually the same, because these two rings are isomorphic to
$$
\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^2+1)
$$
In all cases, the ring operations are the natural ones induced by the quotient map.