# Precise definition of $\mathbb{Z}_n[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have seen the following definition: If $R$ is a subring of $R'$ and $a\in R'$. Then
$$
R[a] = \{f(a): f\in R[x]\}.
$$
This explains well what, for examle, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ are.

My question is how one defines things like $\mathbb{Z}_n[i]$. Here $i\in \mathbb{C}$. The problem is that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (in the definitions that I have seen) is not a subring of $\mathbb{C}$, so the above definition doesn't work. I get how to actually work with these rings, so I am just asking about the precise definition.

EDIT: I see (with the current answer and with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607063/how-to-show-that-mathbbz-5i-a-bia-b-in-mathbbz-5-is-a-ring)) that one can do this with quotient rings. I guess my question is if there is a more fundamental way of defining it.

Comment: Define  $\Bbb Z[i] $ and then use the canonical map?

Comment: @krirkrirk: canonical map? So $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: Yes ; I'm not sure this is the actual definition though.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607063/how-to-show-that-mathbbz-5i-a-bia-b-in-mathbbz-5-is-a-ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two definitions that people use for rings of this form:

> **Definition:** Let $R$ be a ring and let $\alpha\not\in R$ be an element of some $R’$ that extends $R$. Then we define $$R[\alpha]=R[x]/\langle\ker\phi_\alpha\rangle$$ where $\phi_\alpha$ is the map from $R[x]\to R$ that sends $x\to\alpha$. We can that $R[\alpha]=R$ when $\alpha\in R$ for completeness.

Notice that when $\alpha$ is transcendental, the kernel of the map is empty and so we get back $R[x]$ as desired. When $\alpha$ is not transcendental, taking this quotient basically enforces a new rule on $x$, namely that it satisfies $\phi_\alpha(x)=0$. This ensures that $x$ satisfies the necessary algebraic properties to “really be $\alpha$.”

> **Definition:** Let $R$ be a ring and let $\alpha$ be an element of some $R’$ that extends $R$. Then we define $R[\alpha]$ to be the
>   unique ring such that
>
> 1. $R[\alpha]$ extends $R$
> 2. $\alpha\in R[\alpha]$
> 3. If $Q$ is a ring that satisfies $1$ and $2$, then $R[\alpha]\leq Q[\alpha]$

The first definition gives a construction of precise the object that satisfies the second definition. Both of these definitions also work for $F(\alpha)$ and $F[\alpha]$ with minor modifications.

Comment: "reciprocity law"?

Comment: @lhf It's been a while since my last number theory course, but I'm pretty sure that there is a reciprocity law that implies that this exchanging of orders is allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is strictly correct. If I read $\mathbf{F}_5(i)$, I'm more likely to think it refers to the field $\mathbf{F}_5$ rather than $\mathbf{F}_5 \times \mathbf{F}_5$. Maybe $i$ is too small to see why; a better example is that I would expect $\mathbf{F}_19(\zeta_5)$ to be a quadratic extension, rather than a larger extension that isn't a field.

Comment: @Hurkyl Which part of this implies that $F_5(i)\cong F_5\times F_5$? I agree that it should come out to being just $F_5$.

Comment: @Stella: The last line, which says $\mathbf{F}_5[i] = \mathbf{F}_5[x] / (x^2 + 1)$

Comment: @Hurkyl That's really interesting, you appear to be be correct. I'll remove that line.

Comment: For those following, I removed the claim that $$\mathbb Z_n[i]=\mathbb{Z}_n[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle\cong\mathbb Z[x]/\langle n,x^2+1\rangle\cong\mathbb Z[i]/n\mathbb Z$$ The issue is that $R[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ introduces a new element to $R$ that satisfies $p(x)$, which causes problems if $R$ already contains an element that satisfied $p(x)$. This equivalence only holds when the polynomial in question contains no roots in the original field/ring/whatever.

Answer (score 4):

I really don't know, but I wouldn't be surprised if $\mathbb{Z}_n[i]$ meant $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: Ok, so there isn't a nice way to define this without doing quotient rings?

Comment: @JohnDoe I don't know.

Comment: ... or even $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle n,x^2+1\rangle$

Comment: @JohnDoe To my mind, one of the main advances of modern algebra is that quotient objects *are* actually *the* nice way.

Comment: @JohnDoe I suspect my second definition is what you are after. That said, I completely agree with Lisyaris.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $i$ is just meant to indicate a primitive fourth root of unity.  It's not meant to be the "same" $i$ as in $\mathbb{C}$.  Strictly speaking this is I guess an abuse of notation, but it's a harmless one *for people already familiar with the subject*.

It's definitely unfair for us to push these notional conveniences on people still learning, though.

Answer (score 1):

Take the set $R=\mathbb{Z}_n\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ with multiplication
$$(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc),$$
and coordinate-wise addition. It is straightforward to check that this is a ring structure on $R$. It is also straightforward to check that the map
$$\phi:R\to \mathbb{Z}_n/\langle x^2+1\rangle$$
given by
$$\phi(a,b)=[a+bx]$$
is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use well-known algebraic numbers like $i$, $\sqrt{7}$, or $\zeta_{7}$ (a primitive seventh root of unity) not as specific objects, but instead as abstract recipes.

Given a field $F$, $F(i)$ then means a (minimal) extension field of $F$ that contains a square root of $-1$. Similarly, $F(\sqrt{7})$ contains a square root of $7$, and $F(\zeta_7)$ contains a seventh root of unity.

Note, incidentally, that these extensions aren't always defined by the "obvious" polynomials. For example, while $\mathbf{F}_3(i) \cong \mathbf{F}_3[x] / (x^2 + 1)$, the field $\mathbf{F}_5$ already contains a square root of $-1$, so $\mathbf{F}_5(i) \cong \mathbf{F}_5$, but $\mathbf{F}_5[x]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbf{F}_5 \times \mathbf{F}_5$.